# changing flutter path from .bash_profile to .zprofile after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: flutter, zsh, macos-catalina

I followed this youtube video that explains how to change the file path but I think it missed up things for me...

This is the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGmN7F4Gfos

I have also attached a screenshot of my terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfQZ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting flutter path in bash_profile or in zprofile, just add it in `/etc/paths`. It will add flutter sdk path to every user.

check below image
[image]

Comment: Adding a directory under your home directory to a global path is probably not a good idea, though. If flutter should be available to all users, then the SDK should be installed somewhere globally as well.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that, in this case we have to set permission for this path global, so it can be accessible form all user account.